# Use appstore using trusted certificate

Tags: certificates

I connected my iPad to my laptop's localproxy. I also installed a trusted digital certificate in my iPad. I am now able to use all HTTPS networks through my iPad except appstore. If I disable proxy, I am able to access appstore. But when I enable proxy, I am able to browse all https sites (facebook,gmail) but not appstore. It says "Cannot connect to appstore". Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about the internals of the App Store, but I suspect this is a result of [Certificate Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) implemented by the App store.

This essentially means that their certificate validation won't just accept any old CA signed certificate, it'll only accept specific certificates or certificates signed by specific CA's.

This seems to be supported by the [mitmproxy documentation](https://mitmproxy.org/doc/features/passthrough.html):

> Some traffic is is protected using certificate pinning and mitmproxy's interception leads to errors. For example, Windows Update or the **Apple App Store** fail to work if mitmproxy is active.

It looks like there's other ways to intercept App Store traffic, but it's not as simple as proxying traffic via a MITM. It looks like it requires a jail-broken device to physically disable certificate validation: https://nabla-c0d3.github.io/blog/2013/08/20/intercepting-the-app-stores-traffic-on-ios/

Generally certificate pinning is considered good practice when the client knows it'll only be connecting to specific services and therefore can validate certificates more strictly. Unfortunately certificate pinning is far rarer in mobile Apps than it should be, especially considering users can't typically verify certificate information manually in an App like they can in a browser.

Comment: I am not able to kill _itunesstored_ process. It fails and replies "No such process" when I use the command given in your link.